# Mysql Bayesian and sort by star ratings

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, bayesian

Say I have two tables. `businesses` and `reviews` for businesses.

`businesses` table:

```
+----+-------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+
```

`reviews` table:

```
+----+-------------+---------+------+
| id | business_id | message | rate |
+----+-------------+---------+------+
```

each review has a `rate` ( 1 to 5 stars )
I want to sort businesses by their reviews rates, based on `Bayesian Ranking` with condition of having at least 2 reviews.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT b.id,
(SELECT COUNT(r.rate) as rr FROM reviews r WHERE r.business_id = b.id) as rr,
(SELECT
        ((COUNT(r.rate) / (COUNT(r.rate) + 2)) AVG(r.rate) + 
        (2 /(COUNT(r.rate) + 2)) 4)
    FROM reviews r where r.business_id = b.id AND rr > 2
) as score
FROM businesses b
order by score desc
LIMIT 4
```

this will output me:

```
+------+----+------------+
| id   | rr | score      |
+------+----+------------+
| 992  | 14 | 4.31250000 |
+------+----+------------+
| 237  | 3  | 4.2000000  |
+------+----+------------+
| 19   | 5  | 4.0000000  |
+------+----+------------+
| 1009 | 12 | 3.9285142  |
+------+----+------------+
```

I have two questions:

1. as you see in `((COUNT(r.rate) / (COUNT(r.rate) + 2)) AVG(r.rate) + 
   (2 /(COUNT(r.rate) + 2)) 4) FROM reviews r where r.business_id = b.id AND rr > 2 )` some functions are running more than once, like `COUNT` or `AVG`. are they running once in background and maybe caches the resuslt? OR run for every single call?
2. is there any equivalent query for this but more optimize?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you even get the 'right' answer?  I think `rr` should not be visible to the second subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would hope that MySQL would optimise the multiple counts away, but not certain.

However you could rearrange you query to join against a sub query. This way you are not performing 2 sub queries for every row.

```
SELECT b.id,
        sub0.rr,
        sub0.score
FROM businesses b
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT r.business_id,
            COUNT(r.rate) AS rr ,
            ((COUNT(r.rate) / (COUNT(r.rate) + 2)) AVG(r.rate) + (2 /(COUNT(r.rate) + 2)) 4) AS score
    FROM reviews r 
    GROUP BY r.business_id
    HAVING rr > 2 
) sub0
ON sub0.business_id = b.id 
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 4
```

Note that the result here are very slightly different as it will exclude records with only 2 reviews, while your query will still return them but with a score of NULL. I have left in the apparent missing operators (ie, before *AVG(r.rate)* and before *4) AS score* from your original query.

Using the above idea you could recode it to return both the count and the average rate in the sub query, and just use the values of those returned columns for the calculation.

```
SELECT b.id,
        sub0.rr,
        ((rr / (rr + 2)) arr + (2 /(rr + 2)) 4) AS score
FROM businesses b
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT r.business_id,
            COUNT(r.rate) AS rr ,
            AVG(r.rate) AS arr
    FROM reviews r 
    GROUP BY r.business_id
    HAVING rr > 2 
) sub0
ON sub0.business_id = b.id 
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 4
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to run your 2nd query but it errors `b.id is unknown` on line 12. in inner-select where. So I changed to this. https://codetidy.com/9750/ , but sub-query get all rr > 2

Comment: @Pars - Oops, fixed. The sub query will get all where the count is > 2, but that is joined back against the business table and the calculation is then performed to calculate the score. So the join to the sub query excludes any with 2 or less reviews, while the ORDER / LIMIT on the main query will limit it to 4 rows returned.